# alias_method chain issue in application controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sorcery

I'm using sorcery for login. In my application controller i'm overwriting sorcery logged_in? method by using alias_method chain as follows.

```
alias_method_chain :logged_in?, sorcery

protected:

  def logged_in?
    sorcery_logged_in? && (current_user.customer? || current_user.activated?)
  end
```

Finally am ending up with  "undefined method `sorcery_logged_in?' for class`ApplicationController'" error

Can anyone help me whats the mistake here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are using `alias_method_chain`, I think you'd try:

```
alias_method_chain :logged_in?, :sourcery
```

And then use the methods `logged_in_without_sourcery?` and `logged_in_with_sourcery?`.

Check the docs of [Module#alias_method_chain](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_method_chain).

Comment: but if u see the documentation source code..Its telling that method names with ? are not valid.     
# Strip out punctuation on predicates or bang methods since
    # e.g. target?_without_feature is not a valid method name.
So what should I do?

Comment: You can have method names with punctuation. Punctuation in the middle of name of the method is invalid, but `alias_method_chain` takes care of it for you. The comment in the source code mislead you, it does not document the method itself, rather explains what it is doing.